# Unable to upload Phonegap Build APK to play.google - You uploaded a debuggable APK error

Tags: cordova, build, apk

Trying to upload a release version APK generated from Phonegap Build to the Google play store.

Getting an error as follows:

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to
>   disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.

But this is a release version? It is not in Debug mode - why this error now?

If I need to add something to the config XML to set debugging to False, what would that be?

I repeat that this is a phonegap Build project - so all I have is html, css, js and image files. These are then zipped up and uploaded to build.phonegap and they generate the IPA and APK etc etc

Answer (score 15):

Martina is correct, but I want to add more details:

You must create a signing key and upload it to PhoneGapBuild to use.

#### Create a Keystore for Signing your build using a java utility called "keytool"

1. Find keytool (it comes with java). I found mine at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin
2. Open command prompt and enter the following commands
3. > cd  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin

   (use whatever dir you found the keytool in)
4. > keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\DIR\APPNAME.keystore -alias APPNAME -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

   (Change DIR and APPNAME to something appropriate)
5. Enter the keystore password (remember this)
6. Answer the questions about yourself: your name, organization, location, etc.
7. DONE: The keystore will be created for your app

#### Remaining Steps:

- Upload that to PhoneGap  Build.
- Unlock the keystore for 1 hour by entering your keystore password
- Build the app

This will create a release version of the .apk that can be uploaded to Google Play.

Answer (score 4):

From the Docs:

> Make sure you deactivate logging and disable the debugging option
>   before you build your application for release. You can deactivate
>   logging by removing calls to Log methods in your source files. You can
>   disable debugging by removing the android:debuggable attribute from
>   the  tag in your manifest file, or by setting the
>   android:debuggable attribute to false in your manifest file. Also,
>   remove any log files or static test files that were created in your
>   project.
>
> Also, you should remove all Debug tracing calls that you added to your
>   code, such as startMethodTracing() and stopMethodTracing() method
>   calls.

Link: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-configure

So in your project manifest xml file, change the debuggable attribute to false.

Comment: Thanks Purus - but there is no "Manifest" file in Phonegap Build. There is a config.xml, in which there is no mention of debugging. In the Phonegap Build itself, debugging is set to Off - then the apk is built.

Comment: You will have that in the platform/android path

Comment: Thanks Purus - So, I specify something like this path in the config.xml
"<feature name="debug-server" required="false" />"
But I need to put platform/android in there ?

Comment: The debuggable option should be already there in the manifest file. change that to false.. It does not matter what you have in build debug value.

Comment: There is no manifest file. There is no platform/android path.All we have is a index.html, config.xml and a few other htm and js files in the root. Then folders for /images and /resources that contain images and icons. This is a build.Phonegap build.......

Comment: How you created your project? using CLI?

Comment: I created the html, css and js files - then configure the config.xml according to the examples in build.phonegap. I then zip up this folder and upload to build.phonegap for building. This generates the APK and IPA files, that are then uploaded to iTunes and playstore. This particular App has been downloaded and submitted to iTunes without issue - but the apk download results in the above error for Playstore

Comment: Any further thoughts or is it the case that Phonegap Build does not do Android any more....

Comment: Phonegap does support Andorid. not sure what's the problem in your case

Comment: Disable the debug-server feature like user3032942 said.  http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/configuring_features.md.html#Features

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a release key for android (using keytool) and added it to your project on phonegap build website and rebuilt your app? (I'm assuming from comments you are using phonegap build).

Answer (score 0):

If you build it with dreamweaver there is automaticly a Projectsettings file created. Set there debug mode to false.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but it could be a good help for others. The problem is the platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml, the 
    `<application android:debuggable="true"...`
must be 
    `<application android:debuggable="false" ...`.
Then build again.